# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `compact' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, mongoid

I am a rails newbie and cant figure out what is wrong with the following relation.
I have some models as below
    class Question
      include Mongoid::Document
      has_one :dep_q, class_name: 'DepQ'
      belongs_to :rep, class_name: "Rep"
    end

```
class DepQ
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :data_holder, class_name: 'DataHolder'
  belongs_to :question, class_name: 'Question'
end

class DataHolder
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :rep, class_name:"Rep"
  belongs_to :dep_q, class_name:"DepQ"
end

class Rep
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :question, class_name: 'Question'
  belongs_to :data_holder, class_name: 'DataHolder'
end
```

I don't know what wrong I am doing here. I don't know why i am getting this error. I can do the following

```
a = Question.new
a.dep_q = DepQ.new
a.dep_q.data_holder = DataHolder.new
a.dep_q.data_holder.rep = Rep.new
```

But, once I create a new Question under Rep I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `compact' for #<Question:0x00000005168cf8>
```

Why am I seeing this error and how can this be solved?

Comment: I have used a class name with that, would that be a problem ? I tried changing that to questions but the error is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Rep has_many questions`, `Rep.questions` is an array.

You should do the following:

```
r = Rep.new
q = Question.new
r.questions << q
```